# How to - Conditional formatting on a cell if its value equals a value of another cell in ANY tab of the Workbook

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

- Excel (Office 2007)
- Workbook with 5 Tabs
- In each tab there's a Column A with absolute URLs in each row
- In each tab there's a Column B which extracts the domain only from the absolute URL written in the neighboring cell in Column A (example: if A1 contain the following value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ , then B1 would contain the following value: stackoverflow.com

So my question (my cry for help actually) would be:
How to make each Column(B) cell in any of the workbook's tabs to get (let's say) a red background whenever the value in the corresponding cell turns out to be equal to the value in another Column(B) cell in ANY of the 5 workbook's tabs.

Practically explained:

December 25th
TAB-1 | In A23 I enter an absolute URL "X/questions/" | B23 creates a value "X"

December 31st
TAB-4 | In A57 I enter an absolute URL "X/something-different/" | B57 creates a value "X"

So I need B57 to automatically get a... red background which is a notification for me that a link from the domain specified in B57 was already processed, in the example above, 6 days ago.

Much obliged ^_^

Answer (score 0):

first press alt + F11 to go into visual basic editor.  Insert a new module and paste this code:

```
Sub Elio()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet
Dim arrLink() As Variant, xrow As Long, arow As Long, alink                 As Variant, i As Long

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set ws4 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
Set ws5 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

i = 0
arow = 0
xrow = 2

Do Until ws1.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
arrLink(arow) = ws1.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
xrow = xrow + 1
arow = arow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
arrLink(arow) = ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
xrow = xrow + 1
arow = arow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws3.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
arrLink(arow) = ws3.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
xrow = xrow + 1
arow = arow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws4.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
arrLink(arow) = ws4.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
xrow = xrow + 1
arow = arow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws5.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
arrLink(arow) = ws5.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
xrow = xrow + 1
arow = arow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws1.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
    For i = LBound(arrLink) To UBound(arrLink)
        If arrLink(i) = ws1.Cells(xrow, 2).Value Then
            ws1.Cells(xrow, 2).Style = "Bad"
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
    For i = LBound(arrLink) To UBound(arrLink)
        If arrLink(i) = ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value Then
            ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Style = "Bad"
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws3.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
    For i = LBound(arrLink) To UBound(arrLink)
        If arrLink(i) = ws3.Cells(xrow, 2).Value Then
            ws3.Cells(xrow, 2).Style = "Bad"
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws4.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
    For i = LBound(arrLink) To UBound(arrLink)
        If arrLink(i) = ws4.Cells(xrow, 2).Value Then
            ws4.Cells(xrow, 2).Style = "Bad"
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

xrow = 2

Do Until ws5.Cells(xrow, 2).Value = ""
    For i = LBound(arrLink) To UBound(arrLink)
        If arrLink(i) = ws5.Cells(xrow, 2).Value Then
            ws5.Cells(xrow, 2).Style = "Bad"
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

This should highlight all cells in the B column on each sheet that has a duplicate value found on any of the other sheets.
All you have to do is make sure the name of each sheet matches the sheet names on your Workbook.  I didn't test this so you might get errors.

Comment: Also if there is any blank spaces between links this code won't work.  If there is let me know and Ill edit.

Comment: I renamed the sheets' names accordingly, wrote a domain in some cell in ColumnB in Sheet1, then wrote it again in some cell in ColumnB in Sheet2 and.... nothing :)

In the meantime I found a different solution for my problem, all the data will be put in 1 Sheet and from there it's easy with the "Duplicate Values...". A bit of filtering and formatting will nicely handle the massive amounts of URLs and it'll show just what I need. If a 'domain cell' becomes red, I'll do my quick search through the whole workbook.

Thank you for your effort, I'll leave the Question open for anyone interested.